# Pandas: local vs global dataframe in functions

Tags: python, function

I dont understand what is the best practice here:

I want to modify dataframe `data` in my function. `data` is defined globally. However, if I specify the `global` option in the function, I necessarily get an error because `data =` defines a local variable.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})

def test(data):
    global data
    data =  data + 1
    return data

test(data) 
SyntaxError: name 'data' is local and global
```

Does that mean I cannot use the `global` argument when working with dataframes?

```
def test2(data):
    data =  data + 1
    return data
```

does not work either. That is the original `data` is not modified.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You dont need Global variable if you are returning the same object, Just comment that part and run the pgm

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to act on the global `data` in your function, don't pass it as a parameter:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     'B' : [1,2,3,4]})
def test():
    global data
    data =  data + 1

test()
```

Another option would be to keep the parameter and assign the result of calling the function:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     'B' : [1,2,3,4]})

def test(data):
   data =  data + 1
   return data

data = test(data)
```

You can see that using the same name for both the global and local variables makes things a bit confusing. If you want to go that route,  using different names could make it a bit easier on the brain:

```
import pandas as pd

g_data = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
                       'B' : [1,2,3,4]})

def test(data):
    data =  data + 1
    return data

g_data = test(g_data)
```

Comment: interesting. but then I dont get why the `return` is needed here. Isnt the dataframe modified inplace at the line `data = data + 1`?

Comment: Correct, it's not needed.

Comment: that actually raises an interesting question. if you do keep the `return` does the data is duplicated in memory? That could crash your computer when working with large datasets. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think there would be any problem with memory in that case because really what gets returned is a reference to the object (essentially a pointer). It's good to think about stuff like that, though!